# Adding service reference (SOAP) on Core 2.0

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am using Core 2.0 and after adding the service reference (SOAP) - I get this error:

Scaffolding service reference code ...
Error:It was not possible to find any compatible framework version

Error:The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.0.5' was not found.

Error: - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:

Error: \

Error: - Alternatively, install the framework version '1.0.5'.

Error:An unknown error occurred while invoking the service metadata component.
Failed to generate service reference.

Comment: Use a proxy service, which will be WEB API with lower version of the .Net Core, calling the SOAP. Direct would be possible

Answer (score 0):

This is an known issue with Visual studio 2017 and it will be fixed in the upcoming version. see more details from here

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/110242/adding-service-reference-on-core-20.html

Answer (score 0):

it's fixed in Visual Studio 2017 - 15.6, you can download the VS2017 Preview to use this feature now.
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-preview-relnotes

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, `.net core 1.0.5 (SDK 1.0.4)`is not installed in your machine. Head over to [.net core download archive](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archive.md) and download the version stated in the error description. For your case it'll be [.net core 1.0.5](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/1.0.5-download.md).
After that, restart visual studio, and choose `Add Service Reference` again, then proceed as per the steps.